# GIT: create and get Branch from a previous commit

Tags: git

I've just created a branch from a previous commit with the command

```
git branch thenewbranch 03771674c482e4611cc48ee120a16a91dfb2793d
```

Now I want to checkout the branch to work with in Eclipse with

```
$ git checkout -b thenewbranch
```

But i got this error

```
fatal: A branch named 'thenewbranch' already exists.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout -b thenewbranch
```

means create a new branch called "thenewbranch" and then go into it

you only need to

```
git checkout thenewbranch
```

> git checkout -b|-B  [] Specifying -b causes a
>   new branch to be created as if git-branch[1] were called and then
>   checked out. In this case you can use the --track or --no-track
>   options, which will be passed to git branch. As a convenience, --track
>   without -b implies branch creation; see the description of --track
>   below.
>
> If -B is given,  is created if it doesn’t exist;
>   otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of

from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify `-b`.
Simply:

```
git branch thenewbranch 03771674c4
git checkout thenewbranch
```

The `-b` option is a different behavior, it means you actually want to create a new branch called `thenewbranch` from you current `HEAD` (implicit).

Answer (score 0):

Always create branch and push the changes.You will not face the problem

```
git checkout -b newbranch 03771674c482e4611cc48ee120a16a91dfb2793d
git push --set-upstream origin newbranch
```

Comment: Unearth a 8 years old question to add an off-topic precision? Seems unnecessary. Or maybe it's me who failed to see the link with OP's question? We don't know if their repo *even has* a remote, to begin with. And either way it's relevant to the initial confusion OP faced.

Comment: Today I had faced same issue..i created branch with checkout did not push it..then i found that commit id is wrong and tried again with new branch git push

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks for reminding me 2016 is 8 years ago.. seems to be 4 years back

Comment: I must admit you have a point there.